# Clojure Speccing a natural number

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

A [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) is a non-negative integer. How would you express that with Clojure Spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could express it as a compound of the `integer?` predicate and whether it's larger than 0 or not.

```
(spec/def ::natural-number
  (spec/and integer? (partial <= 0)))

(spec/exercise ::natural-number)
=> ([0 0] [0 0] [0 0] [1 1] [5 5] [5 5] [0 0] [0 0] [0 0] [19 19])
```

This matches both fixed and arbitrary precision integers:

```
(spec/valid? ::natural-number (long 0))
    => true
(spec/valid? ::natural-number (int 0))
    => true
(spec/valid? ::natural-number (bigint 0))
=> true
```

Answer (score 6):

This is already a predicate function in 1.9 which matches fixed precision non-negative integers:

```
(s/valid? nat-int? 1)
; true
```

Note however that this does *not* match arbitrary precision integers like bigints:

```
(s/valid? nat-int? (bigint 1))
; false
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also the `spec/int-in` function which allows you to specify a range like

```
(spec/def ::natural-number
  (spec/int-in 0 Integer/MAX_VALUE))

(spec/exercise ::natural-number)
=> ([1 1] [1 1] [0 0] [0 0] [1 1] [3 3] [4 4] [4 4] [50 50] [1 1])
```

Note however that `spec/int-in` does *not* match arbitrary precision integers like `bigint`:

```
(spec/valid? (spec/int-in 0 Integer/MAX_VALUE) (bigint 1))
=> false
```

Comment: This looks iffy: surely non-negative `Double`s (the Clojure default) and `BigInt`s are natural numbers too?

Comment: Double's are floating point precision, so most of them no. But non-negative BigInts are definitely natural numbers for which this spec won't work.

Comment: Oops! Meant `Long`, not `Double`.

Comment: user=> (spec/conform ::natural-number (long 10))
10. 
user=> (spec/conform ::natural-number (bigint 10))
:clojure.spec/invalid.